How long must a sample last in a molecular dynamics run for it to be considered non-labile?
So I have a few unusual molecules and I wanted to know whether or not they are kinetically stable (non-labile) across a certain range of temperatures. The methods for synthesizing these molecules isn't known, for they are novel and a product of careful engineering and imagination.
I'm trying to theoretically argue for the kinetic (or in-)stability of these molecules via Molecular Dynamics runs. The idea is that if the simulation box containing a sample of my molecules can go at least a threshold time $\tau$ without decomposing or spontaneously reacting in anyway, then I can have, say $95\%$ confidence that the sample is kinetically stable for the specific conditions of pressure, temperature, density and/or concentration of the simulation run.
I would still have to do a lot of MD runs for several distinct conditions but at least I would have a good measure stick against which to judge all of them.
So my question is: Is there a way to systematically calculate $\tau$?

This question may be more appropriate at Matter Modeling SE.

Note the title and the question at the end of the body of your post do not match, in fact are very different. And what do you mean by "systematic"? You wonder how to determine tau, or whether tau is longer than a threshold? If the molecules are stable, determining tau using a simulation by monitoring conversion to products may be very costly (not practical) but you may conclude that it is longer than the time you are willing to invest. You might also be able to sample formation of an activated state or intermediate.

Really quite a few more details are required to make this a good qustion - at the very least could you give us an estimate of what you expect tau to be? But I suspect this will prove to be a very, errr..., ambitious project.

@BuckThorn They are the same question, phrased differently. Tau is the time I should simulate if I want to be 95% confident that the sample in the simulation box is non-labile under the simulation conditions of  temperature, pressure, etc.. So finding tau is the same as figuring out how long the sample must last in the MD run for it to be considered non-labile with some degree of confidence. I want to know if there is a systematic way to approach the problem, one piece of statistics that tie this time tau with a confidence interval and provides a way to estimate it.

@BuckThorn I am following your advice and also porting the questions ipsis litteris to the Matter Modeling SE, which I did not know exist. I'll just wait a bit so that we can iron out the details and turn this into a clear, good question before reposting. Unless an answer comes along, then reposting won't be needed.

You can't know the average time for 95% to decay (call it t(95%)) without knowing tau (the decay time constant). For instance, assuming exponential decay t(95%) ~= 3 tau.
